# Telerik Rich Text Editor: apply style for whole content

Tags: html, telerik, rich-text-editor

I'm using Telerik's Rich Text Editor. I have following piece of HTML:

```
<h2>Header</h2>
<p>text</p>
```

When I apply custom style for this page in design mode, I get following result:

```
<h2><span class="customStyle">Header</span></h2>
<p><span class="customStyle">text</span></p>
```

Is it possible to configure RTE to apply style for whole content? For example:

```
<span class="customStyle"><h2>Header</h2>
<p>text</p></span>
```

Comment: You cannot have a block-level element (h2, p) inside of an inline element (span). What style are you trying to add to an h2 element that you want to apply to the paragraph as well?

Comment: @Kramb, I use my custom style, which has two implementations - for `h2` and `p` as well. I can't figure out how to apply this style for whole content, instead of applying for each string.

Comment: Wrap it in a div, give the div the class customStyle.

Comment: @Kramb, I need to do it in Rich Text Editor design mode. I don't have to change raw html.